# How to change the value of value in BASH?

Tags: bash, pointers

Let's say I have the following:

```
Vegetable=Potato ( Kind of vegetable that i have )
Potato=3 ( quantity available )
```

If I want to know how many vegetables I have (from a script where I have access only to variable `Vegetable`), I would do the following:

```
Quantity=${!Vegetable}
```

But let's say I take one `Potato` then I want to update the quantity, I should be able to do the following:

```
${Vegetable}=$(expr ${!Vegetable} - 1)
```

However, this doesn't work. Could someone please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
eval ${Vegetable}=$(expr ${!Vegetable} - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
declare $Vegetable=$((${!Vegetable} - 1))
```

You don't need to use `expr`, by the way. As you can see, Bash can handle integer arithmetic.

See [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) for more information on indirection in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

with bash 4.0 you can make use of associative arrays

```
declare -A VEGETABLE
VEGETABLE["Potato"]=3
VEGETABLE["Potato"]=$((VEGETABLE["Potato"]-1))
echo ${VEGETABLE["Potato"]}
```